# jQuery: How do you make a panel stay visible on mouseover, after a slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, mouseover, slidetoggle, mouseout

When the mouse stays over the `slide` div, the `slide_panel` div will become visible.

However, when the mouse then exits the `slide` div and is over the content in the `slide_panel`, the panel does *not* remain visible.

So, once the panel is initially visible, how do you keep the toggled panel visible on `mouseover`?

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "slide">category:</div>
<div class = "slide_panel">
     <a href = "#" title = "">asdf</a><br />
     <a href = "#" title = "">qwerty</a><br />
</div>

<div class = "slide">another category:</div>
<div class = "slide_panel">
     <a href = "#" title = "">another asdf</a><br />
     <a href = "#" title = "">another qwerty</a><br />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".slide").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).next(".slide_panel").slideToggle();

}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).next(".slide_panel").slideToggle();
});
```

---

**Edit:**

*I want the `slide_panel` to then disappear on `mouseout`, to essentially behave like a dropdown menu.*

Comment: use a timeout when leaving the element, 700 ms ought to do. if the mouse enters the panel, clear the timeout, otherwise, let the timeout finish and hide the panel.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy, however I want the hidden panel to remain visible indefinitely on `mouseover` of the `slide_panel`..

Comment: when $('.slide_panel') become visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can wrap your submenus under your main menu you can avoid this issue.

#### Html

```
<div class="slide">category:
    <div class="slide_panel"> <a href="#" title="">asdf</a>
        <br /> <a href="#" title="">qwerty</a>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">another category:
    <div class="slide_panel"> <a href="#" title="">another asdf</a>
        <br /> <a href="#" title="">another qwerty</a>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
 $(".slide").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).find(".slide_panel").stop().slideToggle();

});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YF5H/)

Comment: This works perfect, thanks @PSL! I am curious though -- how does `slideToggle()` get initially triggered in this case? Is `.stop()` only executed when it returns true? (when there is something to stop)

Comment: @IanCampbell Not really i have dsplay non provided in the CSS which makes it hidden. also you should use mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout due to event bubbling issues. Stop is provided to cancel any pending animation in case if you hover over and out continuously...

Answer (score 1):

You're firing the `slideToggle` twice, causing it to open on mouse over and close on mouseout. Doing nothing on mouse out should keep it open, unless `mouseover` has two states which I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic B-c. I may have mislead you though -- what you are suggesting *does* work, but I still want the panel to disappear on `mouseout` of the `slide_panel`.

Comment: @IanCampbell Based on that response right there, the issue is inherit within the design and markup of your structure. Child elements of hidden parent elements will not be visible -- for several reasons. the solution here, is to not make the element a child of the parent [insinuating a position based relationship], OR, to wrap them both in a separate parent (so they're siblings).

Comment: I'm on a mobile atm, so its too tricky to write code, if no ones helped you create a working function by tomorrow I'll try to whip one up.

Comment: Also note to any moderators: I'm not sure what community wiki is, selected by accident because the buttons are a little bit small on nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReQ2Z/4/)

JS:

```
$(".slide").mouseover(function () {
    $(".slide_panel").stop(true, true);
    $(".slide_panel").hide(0);
    $($(this).next(".slide_panel")[0]).slideToggle();

}).mouseout(function () {
    $(".slide_panel:visible").slideToggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.slide_panel {
  display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Mouseout handle event has been updated. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReQ2Z/4/) too.

```
$(".slide").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".slide_panel").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Stiger! However, the `'slide_panel` still disappears on `mouseenter` in this case.

Comment: When `mouseenter` in `slide`, the 'slie_panel' will visible. When `mouseenter` in 'slide_panel', 'slide_panel' will disappears. Is this right?

Comment: Ya, that's the behavior that is undesirable to me though. It appears that the root of the problem is in my html structure though, as Ohgodwhy and PSL have suggested.

Comment: I think my fiddle do it in right way and I don't change your html code, just javascript and css

Comment: Aha, so replacing the `mouseout` handler's content with the line `$(this).find(".slide_panel").stop().slideToggle();` (taken from PSL's answer) will produce the desired result.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot @Stiger! That's an interesting variation -- I like how each set of links remains open, and closes when the other opens. I noticed that removing the line `$(".slide_panel").hide(0);` from the `mouseover` event in the new fiddle will allow the links to individually close and open. Thanks again for your help!